# Cancelling async webservice call in windows phone

Tags: web-services, silverlight, asynchronous, windows-phone

I'm developing a windows phone app that consumes a .Net Web Service (develop also by me). When I call the a Web Service method a do it asynchronously and don't block the UI. For example, here's a code sample for asking the server for a list o flights Arrivals.

```
service.MobileWSSoapClient Proxy { get; set; }
Proxy = new service.MobileWSSoapClient();
Proxy.GetArrivalsCompleted += proxy_GetArrivalsCompleted;
Proxy.GetArrivalsAsync(searchFilter);
```

This way I give the freedom to the user to call again the same method or another one (ex: refreshing the arrival list or searching for a particular arrival). In case the user generates a new call to the services, the app should "cancel" the first call and only show the result of the last call. I think that is technically impossible to Cancel a web service call that already went to the server, we should wait for the server response and then ignore it. Knowing that, it would be helpful to mark somehow that call as obsolete. It would be enough to receive an error as a response of that obsolete call. I'll write a pseudo code of what I imagine/need.

```
void proxy_GetArrivalsCompleted(object sender, service.GetArrivalsCompletedEventArgs e){

   if (e.Error == null){ 
       // DO WORK
   }
   else 
   {
      if(e.Error == Server Exception || e.Error == Connection Exception){
         MessageBox.Show("error");
      }
      else if (e.Error == obsolete call){
        // DO NOTHING
      }
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for your scenario. So, when the user calls again to the web service you can cancel your backgroundworker process that will end the service call.

How to use BackgroundWorker [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: when I call the web server from the BackgroundWorker  it just call it and ends it's work. Meaning that it doesn't wait until the server response.